# Jenkins: https.protocols

Tags: java, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

In Jenkins (v1.599), in a Maven Release build, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy
(default-deploy) on project myArtifactId: Failed to deploy
artifacts: Could not transfer artifact
myGroupdId:myArtifactId:pom:myVersion from/to
sonatype-nexus-staging
(https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/): peer
not authenticated -> [Help 1]
```

I had this first in a build which uses Java SE 7, but now I also have the issue in a build which uses Java SE 8.

After some research I found out that the issue happens because of the https.protocols property.

I noticed this line in the output almost at the top:

```
[workspace] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle//bin/java
-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3 -Dforce.http.jre.executor=true -cp /opt/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.6.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar
org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /usr/share/maven
/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.49.jar
/opt/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.6.jar
/opt/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.6.jar
37213
```

Note the parameter

```
-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3
```

I'm not sure what this call does or what it's effect is. The mvn calls come later and thus should start a different JVM (even several as the Maven Release Plugin forks the process).

Also note that the [default values for https.protocols](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https) are TLSv1 (Java SE 7) and TLSv1.2 (Java SE 8).

Setting this parameter in the job configuration has no effect, but if configure the Maven Release Plugin like this:

```
   <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${plugin.release.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <mavenExecutorId>forked-path</mavenExecutorId>
            <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
            <arguments>-Psonatype-oss-release -Dusername=${username} -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2</arguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

then the release runs fine.

My questions:

- Where does this -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3 come from?
- Is it really the source of the issue? It seems to be a different JVM instance...
- If it is the source, where can I configure/ remove this parameter?

**Update**

I checked MAVEN_OPTS at:

- Jenkins -> Configuration
- /etc/default/jenkins
- env | grep MAVEN_OPTS

The property is not defined there.

Comment: check whether it has set in `Global MAVEN_OPTS` under `configure jenkins`

Comment: No one has an idea where this coming from? Does anybody else see this property in their output?

Answer (score 2):

> peer not authenticated -> [Help 1]

The client is not able to verify the certs. This could be because the server has disabled SSLv3.

- http://www.cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-3566
- https://access.redhat.com/articles/1232123
- http://disablessl3.com/

> Where does this -Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3 come from?

don't know; you may have more luck searching your server settings / job config / grepping your source code.

> Is it really the source of the issue? It seems to be a different JVM instance...

If SSLv3 is disabled on the server and your client is configured to talk only SSLv3 then it is not going to work. You can pass in multiple protocols

e.g. `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`

> If it is the source, where can I configure/ remove this parameter?

Seems like you already found that configuring the plugin works just fine.
You could try overriding `_JAVA_OPTIONS` in your slave environment.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't really add any new information, did it?

Comment: With different JVM I meant that the Maven Release Plugin starts a new JVM instance, AFAIK. And AFAIK it doesn't inherit the properties of the first instance. So I'm talking only about client side JVMs. It's clear that the https protocols of the client and server JVMs have to match.

Comment: Do you see this property in the outputs of your Jenkins Maven jobs as well?

Comment: @Puce, considering this was the first answer, and explained why SSLv3 may be disabled on the server, this is new information.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I was having this error from a github integration plugin:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version`

Changing the Jenkins config file on the server adding `-Dhttps.protocols` config solved the problem
[Docs to change the config file](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/209715698-How-to-add-Java-arguments-to-Jenkins-)

Answer (score 0):

Could it come from the JVM properties? Everything that comes before "-cp" in the call

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle//bin/java
-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3 -Dforce.http.jre.executor=true -cp   /opt/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.6.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar
org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /usr/share/maven
/var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.49.jar
/opt/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.6.jar
/opt/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.6.jar
```

comes from system properties, see https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/util/JVMBuilder.java

Do you see anything in

< your-Jenkins-URL >/systemInfo

It seems that JVM properties in Maven jobs are taken from Jenkins system properties, see
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16331

Answer (score -1):

> Where does this `-Dhttps.protocols=SSLv3` come from?

I would say Jenkins or the way you start up your Jenkins job.

> Is it really the source of the issue? It seems to be a different JVM
>   instance...

If you only enable SSLv3 it means both client and server needs to allow and know how to talk it. SSLv3 is barely considered safe nowadays and you should change it to atleast TLSv1

> If it is the source, where can I configure/ remove this parameter?

In your Jenkins config or the script that starts your job. Sometimes Jenkins can "inherit" the environment from how it was started itself. Check your default environment Jenkins is started in, your Jenkins JDK/Java system config, your Jenkins job and possible your slave host config where the job is run.

Comment: Yes, it seems clear that SSLv3 is somehow the problem, since the issue vanished once I added -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 to the the Maven Release Plugin configuration. But this should be the default (for Java SE 8). 
This Jenkins instance is actually running locally on my notebook. There are no slaves. I checked all the configuration I know (see question), but I couldn't find any SSLv3 configuration. Where else could I look for this? You think it could be in the jenkins script? (I don't have the notebook here to check currently.) Where else could I look?

Comment: Since none of the answers really answered my question, the bounty is almost over, it would be a pity to just loose the points and since you have fewer points than dnozay, I will grant you the bounty points. I still hope I can find an answer to my question, though, so I can clean up my POM files from this parameter again.

Comment: With different JVM I meant that the Maven Release Plugin starts a new JVM instance, AFAIK. And AFAIK it doesn't inherit the properties of the first instance. So I'm talking only about client side JVMs. It's clear that the https protocols of the client and server JVMs have to match.

Comment: It would be under your job Properties. You don't have anything under the sections Properties or JVM Options in the Configure Job page?
You can also try to search your whole Jenkins installation for the SSLv3 string and see if it is in the Jenkins config. If not, it would be something outside Jenkins.

Comment: I will double check but I fairly sure that I haven't any such configurations in my jobs.

Comment: Do you see this property in the outputs of your Jenkins Maven jobs as well?

Comment: I thought you wanted to find out where SSLv3 came from... I don't know if you can force the Maven release plugin to start a different JVM or send it a different https.protocol value.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm looking for the source of this property. What I'm saying, as it is the Maven Release Plugin does already start a new JVM instance, AFAIK (mavenExecutorId=forked-path).